# CurrentVersion targets - WPF c# net472

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, wpf-style

**Description**

I have a large solution, will be a many wpf projects. I would a create one project with resources (wpf resources, usercontrols etc). But when i compile this, i am getting an currentversion.targets errors. I dont know, what i doing bad. I created a test solution, and it is the same issue. I am using a jetbrains rider, release version. I adding screenshot.

**Screenshot**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/elvu2.jpg

**Errors**

first:

> "Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4377, 5): [MSB3021] Nie można
>   skopiować pliku
>   „C:\Users\Kacpii\RiderProjects\WpfStyles\ResProj\bin\Debug\net472\ResProj.dll”
>   do „bin\Debug\ResProj.dll”. Proces nie może uzyskać dostępu do pliku
>   „bin\Debug\ResProj.dll”, ponieważ jest on używany przez inny proces."

second:

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4377, 5): [MSB3027] Nie można
>   skopiować
>   „C:\Users\Kacpii\RiderProjects\WpfStyles\ResProj\bin\Debug\net472\ResProj.dll”
>   do „bin\Debug\ResProj.dll”. Przekroczono liczbę ponownych prób 10.
>   Niepowodzenie. Plik jest zablokowany przez: „  (12588)”

Comment: Sounds like teh Compiler has an isue finding or using a file. "Debug\net472\ResProj.dll" specfically. But I can not really parse those errors messages text.

Comment: 1st error: Google translate says this is Polish for "Unable to copy file" [filepath] | [do] is abigious. "To" would be the obvious, "into" a second and "with" my 3rd guess | "The process cannot access the file" [relative filepath] "because it is used by another process."

Comment: The 2nd one is: "Unable to copy" [absolute filepath] [do] [relative filepath] "The number of retries has been exceeded 10. Failure. The file is locked by: [a process ID]

Comment: A ok, i forget about polish errors.

Comment: Any idea what that process could be? Should be easy to find in the TaskManager, under Details.

Comment: Anything, it is very strange for me. It cannot be any my process, maybe compiler do something with him

Comment: Well, we can not debug it because we are not in front of that computer. Wich Process is given wich ID is non-deterministic. It is basically just a running counter of "processes started".

Comment: What does it mean? Now i am creating an wpfapp in netcore3 and that works. But it is not solution for my problem.

Comment: The message means exactly what it says: "Can not open the file for copy/read, because some other process has it open" Followed by a Process ID. If you do not tell us the name of the process, we can not help you.

Comment: I am know, but i dont know any process, who can using this dll at compilation time. In visual studio i have seen the same errors.  Even antivirus has turned of.

Comment: Sorry, but my Crystall got a Crack when I last send it to be polished. I do not drink enough tea for tea leaf readings. And I can never shuffle any Card deck, Tarot is no exception. **So I really need you to give me the information requested:** Get a current process ID -> Go into Taskmanger -> Register Card Details (or whatever lists PID's) -> Sort by PID column -> Find name of the process with said ID.

Comment: Go to the "Project Dependencies" and try to set projects compilation order. In this case the **WpfStyles** should be compiled after the **ResProj**. In some cases, one Visual Studio compilation thread can block (access error) another if the correct compilation sequence is not set.

Comment: Did not work, i have tried before